# I made Vanillite forget Avalanche by mistake. Is there any way to teach it back to him?

Tags: pokemon-series

Well, title says it all. I hit the wrong button by mistake and Vanillite forgot Avalanche. Now my kid whom I was "helping out" is inconsolable.

As far as I can tell there is no way to teach Avalanche via a TM. Is all hope of teaching it back to the Vanillite lost then? The Vanillite is at level 31.

Comment: There was no saved game before that?

Comment: There was, but it seems the game got auto-saved after exiting the Celestial Tower on Route 7. This was after I made Vanillite forget the move.

Comment: I still draw the line at anthropomorphic icecream.

Comment: @Raven Trubbish is way worse than Vanillite.

Comment: @Strix - but Grimer set a precedent. There is no precedent for ice cream with eyes.

Comment: I still think the most unfortunate English name for a Pokémon is [Conkeldurr](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Conkeldurr_(Pok%C3%A9mon)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you get a [Heart Scale](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Heart_scale#Heart_Scale), you can give it to the [Move Relearner](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Move_relearner#Generation_V) in Mistralton City to have your Vanillite re-learn Avalanche.

Comment: For the record, there's one of these guys in every game since 3rd gen, I believe.  (They always want Heart Scales, except I think in XD.)